# Angular router links not working in Html content

Tags: angular, froala

My app do have some content contributed by user from a richtext editor (froala), and the content might contain some internal reference to another page. I like to make those routerlink like switching page instead of opening another. However, it is not working neither as innerHtml nor froalaView directive.

Comment: What does your code looks like?

Comment: Let say i have some html like 

`let html = '<div>some message <a [routerLink]="somewhere_internal>">Link</a></div>';`

then in the component html

`<div [innerHtml]="html"></div>`

the router link wont work

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it my own with reference to others, wannaa share for those who have the same question

```
@ViewChild('articleContent', {read: ViewContainerRef}) 
articleContentRef: ViewContainerRef;
private injector: Injector;

constructor(
injector: Injector,
private compiler: Compiler,
) {
this.injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(COMPILER_PROVIDERS, injector);
this.compiler = this.injector.get(Compiler);        
this.init();    
}

init() {
const compMetadata = new Component({
    selector: 'article-content',
    template: this.article.content,
});                        
const cmpClass = class DynamicComponent { };
const decoratedCmp = Component(compMetadata)(cmpClass);        

const moduleMetaData = new NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp], entryComponents: [decoratedCmp]
});
const cmpModule = class DynamicHtmlModule { };
const decoratedModule = NgModule(moduleMetaData)(cmpModule);

const moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any> = this.compiler.compileModuleSync(decoratedModule);
const moduleRef: NgModuleRef<any> = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);

const injector = moduleRef.injector;

this.componentRef = this.articleContentRef.createComponent<any>(
  injector.get(ComponentFactoryResolver).resolveComponentFactory(decoratedCmp),
  0,
  injector);            
}
```